# Display Data according to the selecttion of the selected option from the auto complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to use a auto complete for a text box , lets say You are selecting Student names.

If u select any of the pre populated names then i want 2 3 more textboxes like rollno, college name etc to be populated  as per the student name to be populated .

If i am not clear , feel free to ask .
Thanks in advance :)

I am using asp.net  and I have almost done the auto complete feature with Jquery autocomplete plugin .
Ajax Answers are also welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [AutoComplete](http://www.asp.net/aJaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete.ashx) control of asp.net ajax control toolkit. When user clicks a name, you can handle it and populate the other controls.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I was unable to handle the select event of the suggestion .. Any code sample will help

Comment: Please refer to the following; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71338/Using-the-AutoComplete-Extender-to-Automatically-P and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2007/06/19/how-to-use-a-key-value-pair-in-your-autocompleteextender.aspx

Comment: Thanks buddy , I am trying to implement that